# jquery border change won't appear

Tags: jquery, css

I have a pretty simple script to display a nice dropdown menu selection.

I want a border around the div to change colors on click, but it won't overwrite the already existing border color.

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select').click(function () {
    $('#optionbox').slideToggle(150);
    $(this).toggleClass('selectborderchange');
  });
});
```

and the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/btyaf/1/

The #select div should toggle border colors from red to blue...

Comment: Shouldn't that be [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)?

Comment: Ha yes you are right.  That doesn't fix the problem though

Answer (score 0):

*classToggle* needs to be *toggleClass*. Here is the working script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select').click(function () {
    $('#optionbox').slideToggle(150);
    $(this).toggleClass('selectborderchange');
  });
});
```

And here's the fiddle:

*edit* =====

I've updated the fix, it works now. To ensure the border changes the parent's previous setting, add the *!important* directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/btyaf/4/

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem.  You're right about the toggleClass - just a spelling error by me.  But the issue is that the change doesn't overwrite the initial border color that was defined by #select

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes:

1. Change `classToggle('selectborderchange')` to `toggleClass('selectborderchange')` in your JS
2. Change `.selectborderchange` to `#select.selectborderchange` in your CSS

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AMTSx/1/)

If you are ever having issues with JQuery, always check your console first!  It would have told you that the method classToggle was not found.

`.selectborderchange` needs to be changed to `#select.selectborderchange` because the red border defined by `#select` is that of an id.  In CSS, any rules created by an id will always override those made by a class.  Even though your select div has the `selectborderchange` class attached to it, the red border defined by the `#select` *id* will always take precedence over the blue border defined by the `.selectborderchange` *class*.

`#select.selectborderchange` selects an id of `#select` and a class of `.selectborderchange`, and since this is more specific that just an id of `#select`, it overrides the red border.

Answer (score 0):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/btyaf/3/

```
.selectborderchange {
    border:1px solid blue !important;   
}
```

toggleClass functions adds the class and not replace, therefore I added !important in css of selectborderchange class so that whenever we get selectborderchange added it overrides the other css.

i hope you get an idea.

Comment: careful, adding !important is usually bad practice in CSS and can lead to a headache in debugging later on.

Comment: @Irvin thanks for the tip, I will remember this. In the current situation this seemed to be the best way as to avoid much alteration to the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Because of selectors specificity: id has more power than a class. 
You need to use this rule in your css file, so it will have enough specificity to change the border for the select too: `#select.selectborderchange { your border}`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/btyaf/8/
This works

HTML:

```
<div id="select" class="red">
  Select :
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select').click(function () {
    $('#optionbox').slideToggle(150);
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    $(this).toggleClass('selectborderchange');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.selectborderchange {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.red {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```